# Get username from access token in auth0

Tags: oauth, auth0

I am using /oauth/token api in auth0 to generate access token for my application. I am able to generate access tokens with following parameters,

```
{"client_id":"**",
"client_secret":"**",
"audience":"https://**/api/v2/","grant_type":"client_credentials", "username" : "***", "password" : "***"}
```

I have 2 questions here

1. the sub claim in token is always my client id. How do i change that to username/user id?.
2. i always get the token when password is incorrect. Does this api not validate the credentials. Am i supposed to use any other API here ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance